# Calling variables defined within "Check for Type" script

Tags: python

I am checking to see if a string a user has entered can be converted into a float. I want to construct this like a loop, where the user is prompted to enter a valid value, and the loop is broken if the value is successfully converted into a float. I also want to use this new, converted value elsewhere in my script for calculations later on.

```
dist_string = raw_input("Enter a distance in meters to use as a buffer: ")
try:
    dist = float(dist_string)
    print dist
except ValueError:
    #Prompt user to enter a number if they entered a string
    dist_string = raw_input("Please enter an integer or float value: ")

print(dist)
```

The following error is raised when I try to call 'dist' outside of the function (I need to use this converted float value elsewhere):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\407_Lab05\Script1.py", line 194, in <module>
    print(dist)
NameError: name 'dist' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If during the assignment of `dist` in your `try` block raises an exception (e.g. `dist_string` cannot be parsed into a `float`), `dist` will not be created. If you attempt to reference a variable that does not exist,`NameError` will be raised.

A potential solution, though I am not entirely sure what you're trying to do with your code, is to add a fallback clause to your exception handling block, just in case the initial declaration of `dist` doesn't work out. Like this:

```
try:
    ...
except ...:
    ...
    dist = None
```

**Edit according to comment:**

If you are trying to take input until it is valid, you'll need to use a `while` loop, as such:

```
while True:
    dist_string = input(...)
    try:
        dist = float(dist_string)
    except ...:
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Using this construct will continue to prompt input until the `dist` value can be properly assigned.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding how to use my own code... I am trying to create a loop essentially, where a user is prompted to enter something that can be converted to a float, and the loop is broken if the user enters a valid value.

Comment: I see. Give me a moment to update my answer, and please include that in your question.

Comment: This worked, but I am confused by why it works -- specifically, how the `while True` clause works. Does the clause look for `ValueError == True`? Why isn't it written like `while ValueError == True`?

Comment: I'll try to update my question to explain, but I'd encourage you to look at the Python documentation for [while loops](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=while#the-while-statement)

Comment: I have, but am confused. I understand the boolean nature of while loops, but what I don't understand is **what** evaluates to true; how the loop knows that if a value error is raised, ie the exception, to exit. Or even, why we need to have a `while True` clause, instead of having just the original statement plus the `else: break` statement.

Comment: Ah I see. Using `while True` simply runs until it breaks. The `else: break` statement breaks the while loop once the assignment of `dist` succeeds.

Comment: In that case, do we even need the `else: break` if it will break anyway once the `dist` assignment succeeds?

Comment: It won't, because simply the assignment of `dist` does not break the loop.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using python 3 or greater version so you have to use `input()` rather than `raw_input()`
For your problem you have to make a variable outside the try except and initialize it with empty later update it on try.
Like This:

```
dist = None
dist_string = input("Enter a distance in meters to use as a buffer: ")
while True:   
    try:
        dist = float(dist_string)
        print(dist)
        break
    except ValueError:
        #Prompt user to enter a number if they entered a string
        dist_string = input("Please enter an integer or float value: ")
        continue

print(dist)
```

Comment: adding  `dist = None` seems to be an unnecessary step.